# Web sockets with spring boot working over http but not https

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, https, spring-websocket

I am developing a Spring Boot web application which uses WebSockets via the `spring-boot-starter-websocket` package and is deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. When I go the the http version of the page everything works perfectly, but when I try to connect with https I can't establish a WebSocket connection. Specifically, the sockjs client I have in my frontend continually retries with wss, xhr, and other fallback protocols. The wss requests have no response, and the other requests get either 403 or 404 status codes. I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar issue, so I don't have any idea what the problem might be.

Here are the configuration files that might be relevant:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/api/socket");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api/websocket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ExternalAuthenticationProvider externalAuth;

    @Autowired
    private InMemoryAuthenticationProvider internalAuth;

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(List.of(externalAuth, internalAuth));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
                .and().csrf()
                        .ignoringAntMatchers("/api/websocket/**")
                        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers("/api/websocket/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/activity/host/**").authenticated()
                        .antMatchers("/api/activity/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/api/users/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().logout()
                        .logoutUrl("/api/auth/logout")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .permitAll();
    }
}
```

This is the endpoint I am trying to hit while debugging:

```
@Controller
public class SocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/test")
    @SendTo("/topic/test")
    public String testConnection() {
        return "CONNECTED";
    }
}
```

If there is any other details that might be helpful to diagnose my issue, please let me know. I have been messing around with this for weeks and can't figure it out.